# How often "fat" is used as an abbreviation for fat cattle?

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

I'm interested to know how often (if at all) "fat" is used as a shortening for [Fat Cattle](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Feeder_cattle).

I think I've found one source that suggests this kind of usage:

> At **fat** auctions in the north, though, prices were higher.
>
> Slaughter steers and heifers sold fully $1 higher at Sioux Falls
> Regional in South Dakota: $115.35/cwt. for Ch 2-3 steers at an average
> of 1,400 lbs.
>
> At the **fat** auction in Tama, Iowa Ch 2-4 steers sold $3.50-$4.00 higher
> at $118.50 and an average weight of 1,338 lbs. Choice heifers sold $3
> higher.
>
> [source](https://cattlecurrent.com/cattle-current-daily-july-18-2019/)

It would also be nice to know if such usage can be found both in American and British English.

Comment: I'm British and I've never heard the term: not even "fat market". However I am not a cattle farmer.

Comment: It appears to be industry-specific jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fat) lists this definition for the noun *fat*:

> A beef cattle fattened for sale.

Other dictionaries don't generally list it, so it seems that this usage is rare outside of the industry.